# Validation @ScriptAssert with access to static methods

Tags: java, bean-validation

The JSR303 Bean Validation implementation Hibernate-Validator (4.1.0) provides the [`org.hibernate.validator.constraints.ScriptAssert`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/ScriptAssert.html) annotation.

I get it working for invocation of not static methods.

```
@ScriptAssert(script="_this.isComplexSubValid(_this.attributeA,_this.attributeB)",
              lang = "javascript")

...
public boolean isComplexSubValid(Object a, Object b)...
```

But now I want to externalize the `isComplexSubValid` as an static method to reuse it in different classes. But I don´t get the static invokation working with the javascript validator.

```
@ScriptAssert(script="ComplexValidation.isComplexSubValid(_this.attributeA,_this.attributeB)",
              lang = "javascript")

public static boolean isComplexSubValid(Object a, Object b)...
```

throws:

> Unexpected exception during isValid call:
>   org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:156)
>   org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:140)
>   org.hibernate.validator.metadata.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:121)
>   org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:327)
>   org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForRedefinedDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:273)
>   org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:256)
>   org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:210)
>   org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:119)
>   org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:86)
>   org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:692)
>   org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doBind(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:807)
>   org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:359)
>   org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:640)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   de.humanfork.security.crsf.IdempotentCsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(IdempotentCsrfPreventionFilter.java:99)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:74)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:113)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

So my question is how to invoke static methods within the script tag?

*Please don't tell me that I can implement my on validator instead of using the @Script tag.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class name of the class with the static method must be fully qualified.

```
ScriptAssert(script="com.example.demo.ComplexValidation.isComplexSubValid(_this.attributeA,_this.attributeB)",
          lang = "javascript")
```

public static boolean isComplexSubValid(Object a, Object b)...